# Question about limit!

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find this limit,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x^{1/2}-1}.$$

I know how to find it using the L'Hospital theorem. I would like to find it without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $z:=x^{1/6}$. It also tends to $1$ as $x\to 1$. Then we have
$$\frac{z^2-1}{z^3-1}=\frac{z+1}{z^2+z+1}\to\frac23$$
as $z\to 1$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think in change of variables :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the limit as follows:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x}-1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}=\frac{(x-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}{(x-1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}=\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}, ~~~x\neq1$$ so your limit is reduced to the following:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}=2/3$$

Comment: Wow, lots of formatting for this answer! ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. I hope you have a nice and fresh times ahead. ;-)

Comment: I'll probably head to bed soon! Nice to see you!

Answer (score -1):

Divide by x-1 in numerator and denominator then give limit saperately
lim x→1 (x^(1/3)) - 1)(x-1)/lim x→1 ((x^(1/2) - 1)/(x-1) = (1/3)/(1/2) = 2/3

Comment: You better try to write with LateX if you want more people to read your comments/answers. In the FAQ section you can find directions on how this is done.